# distribution of image data?

Tags: machine-learning, neural-networks, conv-neural-network, image-processing

(I don't much about deep learning, but have been playing with a few things and have some questions.)

I took the (pretrained on imagenet) resnet18 [model from pytorch](https://pytorch.org/vision/0.8/models.html), removed the last fully-connected layer and ran the [STL-10](https://cs.stanford.edu/%7Eacoates/stl10/) images (96 pixels square) through it.  The result is a 512-dimensional data set.  It seems that this data is spherical in that the variance in norms is $\approx0.01$ and all of the data is in a spherical shell of radius between 20 and 22.  It also seems that none of the features are redundant as seen on this PCA explained variance curve:

[image]

I did something similar, running the [CIFAR-10](https://www.cs.toronto.edu/%7Ekriz/cifar.html) images (32 pixels square) through the pretrained densenet121 [model from pytorch](https://pytorch.org/vision/0.8/models.html) (with the last linear layer removed), getting 1024-dimensional data.  This data doesn't seem to be spherical at all, and there is a lot of redundancy among the features:

[image]

I assume the observations above come from the architecture of the models, which I know nothing about really.  My questions are:

1. Are there any rules of thumb about the distribution of image data run through some of the popular networks?
2. Is there a reason why the resnet produces spherically distributed data?
3. Is there a reason why the densenet produces a lot of dependent data?

(Note:  To use pytorch models, images were resized to 256 pixels square and center-cropped at 224 pixels square.)

Comment: You should maybe compare the two curves on the same scale?

Comment: In (3) you say that you resized the images. Are you making small images larger? What size are the images before and after resizing? What method do you use for resizing?

Comment: If you want to compare the two models, I would recommend using the same data.